# JavaScript induced CSS animation not working

Tags: javascript, css, animation, transition

Following advice from [this CSS Tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/), I tried to write some code to induce a CSS transition using JavaScript.

(Here's my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rbyfzkqc/).)

**HTML:**

```
<button id="button" onclick="doMove2()" value="play">Play</button>
<div class="foo"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#button {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 185px;
    left: 0px;
}

.foo {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px dashed black;
    left: 0px;
    top: 120px;
}

.foo.horizTranslate {
    -webkit-transition: 3s;
    -moz-transition: 3s;
    -ms-transition: 3s;
    -o-transition: 3s;
     transition: 3s;
     margin-left: 50% !important;
 }
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var foo = document.getElementsByClassName('foo')[0];

function doMove2(){
    document.getElementById("button").onclick = function(){

        if(this.innerHTML === 'Play'){
            this.innerHTML = 'Pause';
            foo.classList.add('horizTranslate');

        } else {
            this.innerHTML = 'Play';
            var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(foo2),
            marginLeft = computedStyle.getPropertyValue('margin-left');
            foo.style.marginLeft = marginLeft;
            foo.classList.remove('horizTranslate');    
        }
    }
}
```

1. Why doesn't this work?
2. Could someone explain the difference between a *transition* and an *animation*?

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: doMove2 is not defined `

Comment: you just need to invoke `doMove2()` to add the event listener, then it works: http://jsfiddle.net/rbyfzkqc/2/

Comment: `doMove2` is being wrapped in an onload function. It works if you do `window.doMove2 = function(){...`.

Comment: thanks pawel, it works on my fiddle now, but it still doesnt work in my files. Do you have any suggestion what it might be?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I don't recommend using jsfiddle, sometimes its glitchy and unreliable.  I use jsbin, check my demo: http://jsbin.com/guceneku/1/

I removed the onclick in your HTML tag, since you already had a trigger in js, so it becomes:

```
<button id="button" value="play">Play</button>
<div class="foo"></div>
```

Next your js becomes:

```
var foo = document.getElementsByClassName('foo')[0];

document.getElementById("button").onclick = function(){
        if(this.innerHTML === 'Play'){
            this.innerHTML = 'Pause';
            foo.classList.add('horizTranslate');
        } else{
            this.innerHTML = 'Play';
            var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(foo2),
            marginLeft = computedStyle.getPropertyValue('margin-left');
            foo.style.marginLeft = marginLeft;
            foo.classList.remove('horizTranslate');    
        }
    }
```

Comment: JSFiddle has always been 100% reliable for me. It's just that a lot of people don't use it properly and aren't caring enough to learn how to use a powerful tool.

Comment: It was because his code was run onLoad instead of in <body>, that's all

Comment: Upvoted because this answer fixes the problem, but disagree with the comment about jsFiddle being glitchy. Outages/downtime aside, I've found it very reliable over the years.

Comment: Yeah I've had mixed feelings about it.  I guess when I really want to just deal with code and not settings, I feel that jsbin tries its best to stay out of your way in a better fashion.  Of course, its subjective.

Answer (score 0):

You have no initial value defined. It's defaulting to a margin of `auto`, and `auto` is not transitionable.

Also, you should define the transitions on the "base" state, otherwise it won't transition when removing the class.

So:

```
.foo {
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px dashed black;
    left:0px;
    top:120px;
    margin-left: 0; /* ADD THIS */
    transition: 3s; /* all browsers support unprefixed now */
}

.foo.horizTranslate {
    margin-left: 50%;
}
```